# Direct access to fields of field in a struct in Rust

Tags: rust

I've been browsing the code of the Rust compiler and I've come across a `struct FnCtxt` which doesn't have a field `tcx : TyCtxt`, however it has a field of type `Inherited` which itself has a field `infcx : InferCtxt`, which has a field `tcx : TyCtxt`.

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4745cbe83e0b3299bfe7f7f305b975c3c09f92db/src/librustc_typeck/check/mod.rs#L545

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4745cbe83e0b3299bfe7f7f305b975c3c09f92db/src/librustc_typeck/check/mod.rs#L220

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4745cbe83e0b3299bfe7f7f305b975c3c09f92db/src/librustc_infer/infer/mod.rs#L283

Now they have an instance `fcx : FnCtx` and call `fcx.tcx.mk_fn_sig(...)`:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4745cbe83e0b3299bfe7f7f305b975c3c09f92db/src/librustc_typeck/check/mod.rs#L1303

Why does this work and what Rust feature do they use here that allows them to do this?

Comment: Please do not post links to code but the code itself.

Comment: But they don't use typical object composition here. FnCtxt doesn't have a tcx field! The following clearly doesn't work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95d5b9309355193b2ffe8f0d48131a74

Comment: So there must be some other feature they use here which allows them to access tcx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FnCtxt` [implements](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4745cbe83e0b3299bfe7f7f305b975c3c09f92db/src/librustc_typeck/check/mod.rs#L624) `Deref<Target=Inherited>` which returns `&self.inh`.

`Inherited` [implements](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4745cbe83e0b3299bfe7f7f305b975c3c09f92db/src/librustc_typeck/check/mod.rs#L262) `Deref<Target=InferCtxt>` which returns `&self.infcx`.

The `Deref` trait allows [coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion) from `&T` to `&U` and can chain together, which is why `fcx.tcx` can be resolved.